# Creating a structure as a button in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, structure

First off, I'm not really sure how to title this question so I apologize if it's vague. I am trying to create a shopping list using ColdFusion and I've ran into a bit of a snag. I want a delete button to appear next to the item that's been created. I have almost everything working, but I don't understand structures enough in ColdFusion to understand what I am doing wrong. Is it similar to a component in React.js? I ran into an issue saying that the variable "button" is not defined. I'm assuming this is because structkeyExists can't identify a single button. Why would this work for form and not for a button?

Here is my code:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submitButt")>
  <cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH">
     INSERT INTO Main(itemDesc) VALUES('#itemDesc#')
  </cfquery>
</cfif>

<cfif structKeyExists(button, "delete_butt")>
  <cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH">
    INSERT INTO Main(itemDesc) VALUES('#itemDesc#')
  </cfquery>
</cfif>


<cfquery datasource="ESC-ADD-TECH" name="items">
        DELETE FROM Main
        WHERE itemDesc = '#itemDesc#'
</cfquery>

<body>
    <div id="myDIV" class="header">
        <h2>My Shopping List</h2>
        <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="itemDesc" placeholder="Title...">
        <input name="submitButt" type="submit" class="addBtn">
        </form>
    </div>

    <cfoutput query="items">
     <li>#items.itemDesc#  <button class="delete" name="delete_butt">x</button></li>
    </cfoutput>

</body>
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do here using a structure? Am I better off creating the button in javascript and try to create a structure as a boolean statement and just have javascript rewrite that value? Kinda just shooting in the dark here, but I would appreciate any and all help.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: I wonder if I can just wrap the button with a form tag

Comment: You should use [cfqueryparam](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html) rather than dumping variables into cfquery blocks. That opens you up to SQL Injection, especially if those variables aren't scoped. ColdFusion has a documented [scope precedence](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html) (search for _Using scopes_)

Comment: @Rain 1) Super jealous you got a really awesome username. Rain is just the best username ever. 2) Thank you very much for the information. This is just for a test than anything else, but I appreciate the advice. I'll keep that as part of my notes. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks, that's my actual name. [cfdump](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdump.html) or the cfscript equivalent [writedump](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/writedump.html) are invaluable when learning ColdFusion. When you're developing, dump **everything** to screen and inspect it. In this case, you could `<cfdump var="#form#"/>` to see what's up. ColdFusion is an inconsistent language with sparse documentation and _weird_ rules. Don't trust it, watch what it's doing. :)

Comment: @Rain That's even more awesome haha. Thanks! I really appreciate that information as well. I've kinda ran into that a bit already trying to make something as simple as this. Another member here said that ColdFusion has probably the best support community out of all of the other languages and so far they're right. Thanks again everyone

Comment: Agreed about `cfqueryparam`. "Good code" never uses raw client values in queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there isn't going to be a "button" structure from your form being submitted.
The first thing to remember is that a ColdFusion structure is just a collection of key/value pairs (similar to a JavaScript object), and unless the value is set, will be undefined.

In your case, the "form" struct exists because you are submitting your page back to itself with your `input[type="submit"]`. Which for a ColdFusion page, will create a form struct with keys for each named input within the submitted form, the values of which are pulled from those elements' value attributes.

If you are trying to use the form struct to handle deleting items, you may be better served using radio buttons/checkboxes to select which item(s) to delete, and set the action to take using the value attribute of your submit buttons.

Using your code as an example:

```
<cfparam name="form.action" type="string" default="none">
<cfswitch expression="#form.action#">
    <cfcase value="insert">
        <!---Your insert query goes here--->
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="delete">
        <!---Your delete query goes here--->
    </cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase></cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>

<!---Your select query--->

<body>
    <form method="post" action="#">
        <div id="myDIV" class="header">
            <h2>My Shopping List</h2>
            <input type="text" name="itemDesc" placeholder="Title...">
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="insert">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <cfoutput query="items">
                <li>#items.itemDesc#  
                    <input type="radio" name="delDesc" value="#items.itemDesc#"/>
                </li>
            </cfoutput>
        </ul>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">Delete</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

In this case you will use `form.itemDesc` when inserting values, and `form.delDesc` when deleting items.

Comment: Wow! Great answer.

Comment: Thank you for this, it's extremely informative and very helpful! Do you have any documents on ColdFusion that can help me prevent asking basic questions? Also Is there any real benefit to using a switch case statement instead of an if else? Asking purely for curiosity.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's hard to find good documentation for ColdFusion outside of Adobe's website. Most of what I know about the language has been from trial and error: echoing what others have said, cfdump is invaluable for figuring out what is going on within a page.
-edit-
As far as using a switch vs if elseif statement; in this case it doesn't make much of a difference if any, it really is more of a personal preference.